# Can I get audio data from a media for a give [audio-track-id] without playing it (using libvlc)?

Tags: c#, libvlc

I'd like to load and save audio data from DVD and movie file (for a given audio-track-id) without playing the whole movie - SO QUICKLY. 
Is it possible with libvlc API calls using C#?

I'm pretty new in VLC usage, but I know how to use libvlc_audio_set_callbacks, so by using callbacks I am able to save it into WAV file.
I also know how to save audio using by the vlc.exe command line.
The problems with these two are that the callbacks working only if it's under playback (so too slowly), and in case of vlc command it's faulting, because as I see there's no warranty to get the audio track I wanted to. It exporting different audio-tracks randomly (but always carefully choosing another one, not what I wanted :-S ).

I used this for command line:

```
vlc.exe  -I dummy dvdsimple:///G:\#1:2-1:2 --audio-track=3 --no-sout-spu --no-sout-video --sout-audio --ttl=-1 --sout "#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst=DVD_Lng3.wav}" vlc://quit
```

I also tested it with:

```
--audio-track-id=48515 //this is the ID from track-descriptions
--audio-language=hun
--audio-language=hu
```

The result is the english track (in most cases), sometimes other...
If I run the command line once, it gives me german, I rerun the same again, and gives me english... so it's pretty random.

I'm working in C#, I could call vlc.exe with command line parameters too, but I can't trust the audio-track-id. 
In case of libvlc I don't know how to save audio data in a quick way without playing it.

If you have any idea in any of the two topics (or where I'm wrong), please let me know.
I don't want you to make my coding work, just need some idea where to go forward.

- **Do I use bad parameters in command line?**
- **Or is there a way in libvlc to speed up the playback (using callbacks) but without wave data speedup ?**

Comment: Have a look at https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp

Comment: Thanks mtz, I'm over it, but who knows... so I checked it again. Still no info. :-(

Comment: Honestly I don't know if libvlc is the best tool for that job. Maybe you should have a look at NAudio

Comment: OK, thanks! I'll look that around too. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems NAudio is for audio, and I'm working with videos.